# Read text file and split it over

Tags: c#

So, I know my headline is a bit confusing, I will explain.

My code looks like this:

```
string filename = "C:\\C#\\maplist.txt"; // please put the text file path.
string filename2 = "C:\\C#\\zemaplist.txt";
string map;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename2);
List<string> maps = new List<string> { };
while ((map = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    maps.Add(map);
}
sr.Close();
for (int i = 0; i < maps.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(maps[i]);
    sw.WriteLine(maps[i]);
}
sw.Close();
```

and what i need to do is when the code read a new line, in my line there is

> "Hey,Hey"

I want to split the `,` from each other so I can take both of them as other parameters, so that the first `Hey` will be added to `maps` and the other `hey` will be `maps2`,

How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of `StreamReader` you can use `File.ReadAllLines()'

Comment: Is it this trivial or you are just using an example? Do you want to split every occurrence of "X,X" in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Split()` function to Split the given String based on delimiter.

Try This:

```
while ((map = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    maps.Add(map.Split(',')[0].Trim()); 
    maps2.Add(map.Split(',')[1].Trim());
}
```

**Simple Code:**

```
using System.IO;

string filename = "C:\\C#\\maplist.txt"; // please put the text file path.
string filename2 = "C:\\C#\\zemaplist.txt";
string map;

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename2);
List<string> maps = new List<string> { };
List<string> maps2 = new List<string> { };
String [] allLines =  File.ReadAllLines(filename);
foreach(String line in allLines)
{
   maps.Add(line.Split(',')[0].Trim());
   maps2.Add(line.Split(',')[1].Trim());
}


for (int i = 0; i < maps.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(maps[i]);
    sw.WriteLine(maps[i]);
}
sw.Close();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
String mapItem1="";
String mapItem2="";
if(maps.Count == maps2.Count)
{
   for(int i=0;i<maps.Count;i++)
   {
      mapItem1=maps[i];
      mapItem2=maps2[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Read my other comments.

Comment: @danish: Thanks, you meant OP wants to split similar words?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I am saying that question is not clear enough.

Comment: I guess this one will work, but i have a prolbme, how can i do for (int i=0; i <maps+maps2?

Comment: This wont work, its takes the first time and give the secoond line for the first line

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((map = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     string[] split = map.Split(','); 
     //First Hey would be split[0], second Hey would be split[1]


     maps.Add(split[0].Trim());
     maps2.Add(split[1].Trim());
}
```

The `Split` method should help you out with that.

If you want to trim leading whitespace characters, you can use the .Trim() method on a string.

Comment: No. "Hey, you are good" fails with your code assuming OP wants to split similar words separated with comma.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails?" Can you tell me more?

Comment: OP, in his question used "Hey, Hey". It could well mean that we need to split same words separated by comma. Your code cannot do that.

Comment: i just have 2 words, the first word is email and the seccond is name will it work?

Comment: It'll work if it's separated by a comma. Since your example of "Hey,Hey" is comma separated, the code I posted should be able to split it.

Comment: I remember there was a chat option here at SO. Maybe in beta or something. It would have been useful here. If you just want to split on comma, this answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Split()`.

```
string heys = "Hey,Hey";
string[] splitArray = heys.Split(',');
```

Then you have:

```
splitArray[0] = "Hey";
splitArray[1] = "Hey";
```

Answer (score -1):

Why even bother reading line by line? Read the entire file, replace the new line chars for a "," (to prevent last and first elements from different lines to be treated as one), and loop through a clean string.

```
string fileContent = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("test.txt"), @"\r", ",");
List<string> mapList = new List<string>();

foreach (string map in Regex.Split(fileContent.Replace(@"\s+", ""), ","))
{
    mapList.Add(map.Trim());
}
```

Comment: This way of reading a file is more expensive compared to Stream.

Comment: Aren't we having a bit of premature optimization? Given the lenght of the file the author described, this is exactly what this method should be used for, isn't it? Simple, not-gigantic files.

Comment: Where did OP mentioned file size?

Comment: You're right, he didn't, I assumed by the structure of the file, I'm sorry. Anyway, I think to a rough max of 5/7 mb, the method is quite affordable, furthermore I was just introducing him to a new way of doing what he wanted.

Comment: No worries. My job has made me think of all ridiculous possibilities and take care of them. That's what shows here too.